# How can I iterate through a Set of objectos (links) and validate if one of them?

Tags: javascript, arrays, validation, iterator, set

I have two modules one has a let res that get all the urls of a file (markdown) the other module was made to iterate those links and validate the ones that are broken and ok. I'm having trouble with iterating them, and exporting the function that has the data of the links.

*this is the module the gets all the urls.*

```
    const markdownPath = require('./core');
    const path = require('path');
    const fs = require('fs'); 
    const getUrls = require("get-urls");

    const markdownSearchLinks = (data) => {

      let res = getUrls(data);
      console.log(res);
    const array1 = [res];

    array1.forEach(function(element) {
      console.log(element);
    });


    };
    module.exports.markdownSearchLinks = markdownSearchLinks;
```

*and this is the module where im validating the urls in a set.*

```
    const markdownSearchLinks = require('./linksrs'); 
    const colors = require('colors');


    const validateLinks = (markdownSearchLinks) => {

    if(validate  == '--validate'){

      markdownSearchLinks.map(element => 

        fetch(element)
        .then(response =>{

          if (res.status >= 200 && res.status < 400) {
            res.status(404).send('Sorry, we cannot find that!');
            res.status(500).send({ error: 'something blew up' });
            element.status = res.status;
            element.statusText = res.statusText;
            resolve(element);

            console.log(`status: ${colors.blue(response.status)}
                         text:${colors.green(response.statusText)} 
                         link:${element.red}`)

          } else {
            element.status = res.status;
            element.statusText = 'Fail';
            resolve(element);
          }
        })
      .catch(() => {
      element.status = '';
      element.statusText = 'Este link no existe';
      resolve(element);
      console.log(element);
    return Promise.all(arrPr)

    .then(res => {
        return res;
        })
          }))
        }
        }

        module.exports.validateLinks= validateLinks;
```

*and my terminal shows this:*

```
   `*Set* {
      'https://ugr.es/~anillos/textos/pdf/2011/EXPO-1.Criptografia/02a04.htm)',
      -all thelinks- } `
```

Comment: You question is very vague and not appealing for an answer.
what troubles do you have ?

Comment: I can´t iterate the links, i want them to show and error or and ok, its just does do anything but show the links without their status even though ive written code that tells him to show its status.